# How can I use DVS tests with the Business Rules service on Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, business-rules

I have set up DVS (Decision Validation Services) tests for my ODM rules, and want to use them for the rulesets deployed on Bluemix. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the Business Rules service on Bluemix does not support Decision Validation Services. Instead, I used my on-premise ODM environment to run the DVS tests on my ruleset, and then deployed it to the Business Rules service.